# How to get Left from a method that returns Future?

Tags: scala

```
def myMethod(myType: String) :Future[Future[Either[List[MyError], MyClass]]] {
   for {
     first <- runWithSeq(firstSource)
   }
   yield {
     runWithSeq(secondSource) 
     .map {s -> 
        val mine = MyClass(s.head, lars)
        val errors = myType match {
          case "all" => Something.someMethod(mine)
        }
        (s, errors)
     } 
     .map { x => 
        x._2.leftMap(xs => { 
          addInfo(x._1.head, xs.toList)
        }).toEither
     }
   }
}

for {
  myStuff <- myMethod("something")
} yield {
  myStuff.collect {
   case(Left(errors), rowNumber) => 
    MyCaseClass(errors, None) //compilation error here
  }
}
```

I get compilation error on `MyCaseClass` that `expected: List[MyError], found: Any`

The signature of `MyCaseClass` is:

```
case class MyCaseClass(myErrors: List[ValidationError])
```

How can I fix this such that I can correctly call `MyCaseClass` inside the `yield`?

Comment: `myMethod` returns Future of Future, so you're unwrapping the first Future inside the for, but there's a second Future inside it before you get to the Either. Something returning `Future[Future[_]]` is a warning sign for me, can this be refactored to return `Future[Either[_]]`?

Comment: @Tom I've updated the question with simplified implementation of `myMethod `. I'm not sure how to get past the `Future[Future` since I need to take stuff from first Future and pass it to the second (as you can see in the implementation). If it can be simplified to just return `Future[Either`, please let me know.

Comment: You should never intentionally use `Future[Future[...]]`. Flattening your Futures will help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code example doesn't make much sense, and doesn't compile, but if `runWithSeq()` returns a `Future` then you should be able to eliminate the double `Future` return type like so.

```
for {
  _    <- runWithSeq(firstSource)
  scnd <- runWithSeq(secondSource)
} yield { ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example is pretty hard to paste and fix

Abstact example for this
Class C may be whatever you want

```
def test(testval: Int)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Future[Either[String, Int]]] = {
  Future(Future{
    if (testval % 2 == 0) Right(testval) else Left("Smth wrong")
  })
}

implicit class FutureEitherExt[A, B](ft: Future[Either[A, B]]) {
  def EitherMatch[C](f1: A => C, f2: B => C)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[C] = {
    ft.map {
      case Left(value) => f1(value)
      case Right(value) => f2(value)
    }
  }
}

val fl: Future[Either[String, Int]] = test(5).flatten

val result: Future[String] = fl.EitherMatch(identity, _.toString)
```